# Gradle 1.2: Exclude directory under resources sourceSets

Tags: gradle

I have development related directory `src/main/resources/certs/test` which is needed for one external library. This has some cert files which are not needed in production build.

At the moment I exclude everything under that directory with following block in `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/test/*'
        }
    }
}
```

This does it job well, but leaves ugly empty directory `test` lying there. What are my options to not include this directory in final war?

I've tried excluding `'**/test'`, but it doesn't work at all.

I use war plugin and Gradle 1.2

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using Gradle 1.1, this works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/test/*'
            exclude 'certs/test'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the following to exclude every file and folder and sub-folder: `resources { exclude '*.*' exclude '**/' }`

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem with production files in a JAR file (though mine were not test files).  I solved it with the following:

```
jar {
    exclude ("DIRECTORY-TO-EXCLUDE/**")
}
```

e.g.

```
jar {
    exclude ("test/**")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common projet layout is to put test files under the `test` source set, this way you don't have to exclude them from the `main` source set.

From the [Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), the default project layout is like this:

```
src/main/java       Production Java source
src/main/resources  Production resources
src/test/java       Test Java source
src/test/resources  Test resources
```

Comment: I know the standard layout. Question is not about layout of my project and how standard it is, but Gradle funcionality to exclude directories. I can reformat my project, but initial question remains.

Comment: This layout is standard, and also [totally impractical](http://blog.ltgt.net/maven-is-broken-by-design) (search for "project layout"). Having dropped it is something I enjoy every day.