# How to exclude all files under a directory in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
 exclude 'org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/gen_approx_portuguese.txt'
}
```

For example, this one will exclude 1 file. But how to exclude all file under a directory?

like:
org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/
folder?
*.* does not work :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle 1.2: Exclude directory under resources sourceSets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617827/gradle-1-2-exclude-directory-under-resources-sourcesets) Although this is source sets it still relates to using the exclude functionality.

Comment: this does not work for me. I tried this. Is there any difference between packaging option and source set? Actually it gives me a lot of Duplicate files copied in APK xxxxxx, so I try to exclude the duplicate files. but there are too files under the same directory. So I try to exclude them all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

wild card can be used to enforce action to multiple file in directory. See  this:-

```
packagingOptions {
 exclude 'org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/*'
}
```

You can also exclude a file/directory with out specifying the full path this way:-

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '**/language/bm/*'
}
```

Note: this will exclude any `language/bm/` any where in the path

Answer (score 0):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts) and [AGP](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) (Android Gradle Plugin) version *7.0.0* and newer:

```kotlin
android {
  // ...
  packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes += "org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/*"
    // OR
    // resources.excludes += setOf(
    //   "org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/*"
    // )
  }
}
```