# How to replace directory in Jar?

Tags: gradle

There is my task:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    exclude {
        it.name.startsWith('assets')
    }
    from 'build/tmp/hello' // assets/application.css
}
```

I want to exclude `assets` directory from my source code and add `assets` directory from `build/tmp/hello` path, but exclude filter prevent it, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle 1.2: Exclude directory under resources sourceSets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617827/gradle-1-2-exclude-directory-under-resources-sourcesets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    exclude 'assets'
    from ('build/tmp/hello/assets') {
        into 'assets'
    }
}
```

Comment: But I get warning with this code: Configuring child specs of a copy task at execution time of the task has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Consider configuring the spec during configuration time, or using a separate task to do the configuration.

Comment: Not sure what you actually did, I edited the answer to make clear, what I have shown is the configuration closure of the task.